# Поиск строки по шаблону

Tags: php

В php есть массив переменных имеющий 4 слова разделяющийся ";" 
К примеру:

```
$a[0] = "xx;yy;zz;kk";
$a[1] = "nn;yy;zz;kk";
$a[2] = "xx;yy;aa;kk";
```

Как мне найти из этого массива строку `"xx;yy;любой_значение;kk"` т.е вместо zz пусть будет любое значение но главное быть именно в виде: `"xx;yy;zz;kk"` либо `"xx;yy;любой_значение;kk"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С использованием регулярных выражений:

```
$str = 'xx;yy;zz;kk';
$str = preg_replace('/((?:.+;){2}).+;(.+)/', '$1любой_значение;$2', $str);
```

С использованием explode+implode:

```
$arr = explode(';', $str);
$arr[2] = 'любой_значение';
$str = implode(';', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
<?php
$a[0] = "xx;yy;zz;kk";
$a[1] = "nn;yy;zz;kk";
$a[2] = "xx;yy;aa;kk";

$regexp = "/xx;yy;[^;]+;kk/";
foreach($a as $element) {
  if(preg_match($regexp, $element)) {
    echo $element."<br />";
  }
}
```